# Next.js / i18next: Language Selector for url with #hash

Tags: reactjs, next.js, i18next

I am using the following Languageselector in my next project:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import i18n from '../src/services/i18n'
import Link from 'next/link'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'


const LanguageSelector = (props) => {
  const [language, setLanguage] = useState(i18n.language);
  const router = useRouter()

  const handleOnclick = (value) => {
    router.push(router.asPath, router.asPath, { locale: value });
  };

  console.log(router);

  return (  
    <>
    <div className={props.className!==undefined&&props.className!==""? ('d-inline-block d-xl-none '+props.className):"d-inline-block d-xl-none "} >
        <select onChange={(e)=>{handleOnclick(e.target.value)}} required defaultValue={router.locale}>
           <option value='de'>Deutsch</option>
           <option value='en'>Enligsh</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    
    <div className="d-none d-xl-block">
      {router.locale==="en"? <div><Link href={router.asPath} locale='de'>DE</Link></div> : <div>DE</div>}
      <p>|</p>
      {router.locale==="de"? <div><Link href={router.asPath} locale='en'>EN</Link></div> : <div>EN</div>}
    </div>
    </>
  )
    
}

export default LanguageSelector

_app.js
```

This does work fine until the visitor is on an URL, that has a # parameter. The URL in browser bar still changes but the language stays the same. How can I change the language on URLs with hash?

EDIT: This is how I am using translation

```
import Layout from '../components/Layout'
import { appWithTranslation } from 'next-i18next';
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

const app = ({Component, pageProps })=> {
  const router = useRouter()

  function updateSchnellzugriffe(value, mobileValue){
    setSchnellzugriffe(value);
    setMobileSchnellzugriffe(mobileValue);
  }

  return (
    <Layout>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Layout>
  )
}
export default appWithTranslation(app)
```

And this is an example of pageComponent

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import { useTranslation } from 'next-i18next';
import { serverSideTranslations } from 'next-i18next/serverSideTranslations';

const home = (props) => {
    const { t } = useTranslation(['common','home']);

    return (
                <h1 >{t("home:headline")}</h1>
        )
};



export async function getStaticProps({ locale }){
    return {
        props: {
      ...await serverSideTranslations(locale, ['common','home']),
        },
    }
}
export default home
```

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the issue using your code, changing the locale with the hash in the URL does change the language for the page/site. You should see the right locale logged in the console if you add `console.log(router.locale)` in the component.

Comment: @juliomalves console log shows the new language i want to switch to, also the URL is updated but my text language is not changed - i really don't get why as it works when there is no # in the URL

Comment: What text language isn't changed?

Comment: the language of the text on my webapp

Comment: How is the text being translated? As far as I can see in the code you shared, no translation is being applied to any text.

Comment: I am using 
`import { appWithTranslation } from 'next-i18next';` in my _app.js and `const {t} = useTranslation('common')` wherever I am using text.

Comment: You'll have to share the relevant code where you actually use and apply the translations. Providing a [mre] would be helpful.

Comment: I added Code Snippets to the question